# Upload file from my local system on Sharepoint

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Please help me with the complete batch file code:

I want to upload file(.xls,csv) onto Sharepoint server using batch file. It should perform:

a> Do a check to see in the sharepoint location if the file exist. If exist then do nothing.
b> If the file do not exist, then 
1.check the local if the file is present in this location or not. If yes then simply upload it n sharepoint. 
2.Step a. again

This batch file will be triggered by windows schedular every 20 mins.
My goal is to upload the files the moment they get generated.

Request you to please help me with the correct code logic which I can implement.

Thankyou for the help n support!

Comment: Anything else you would like us to do? SO is not a code writing service center. If you have a specific problem then post the same.

Comment: If you mount the Sharepoint folder as a network drive, you can simply use `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of the SharePoint Multiple File Upload Script;

```
function Copy-FilestoSP
{
   Param (
       [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$LocalPath, 
       [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SiteUrl, 
       [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Library, 
       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$LibraryStartFolder, 
       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$ManifestFilePath, 
       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$IncludeSubFolders,
          [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Approve,
          [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$CheckIn,
          [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Overwrite,
          [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$FlattenStructure
           )

try
{

#Get web and document library objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
$docLibrary = $web.Lists[$Library]

#Load metadata manifest file, if specified
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ManifestFilePath')) {    
    $metadataManifest = [xml] (Get-Content ($ManifestFilePath))
}
else
{
    write-host "Manifest file not specified for categorising uploaded documents"
}

#Check for the LibraryStartFolder parameter to specify a root folder
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('LibraryStartFolder')) {
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($docLibrary.Title + $LibraryStartFolder)
}
else
{
    $folder = $docLibrary.RootFolder
}

#Attach to local folder and enumerate through all files
if($IncludeSubFolders) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem $LocalPath -Recurse
}
else
{
    $files = Get-ChildItem $LocalPath
}

$files | ForEach-Object {

    #Check if the object is a folder - if so, create it in doc library
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
        if (($IncludeSubFolders) -and (!$FlattenStructure)) {
            #Generate folder path for creation in SharePoint
            #by looking at the parent folder on the local path
            $spFolderPath = ($_.Parent.FullName.Replace($LocalPath,"")).Replace("\","/")

            #Get the folder into which the new folder will be created
            #by adding the folder path generated above, if one existed
            if ($spFolderPath -eq "") {
                $currentFolder = $web.GetFolder($folder.Url)
            }
            else
            {
                $currentFolder = $web.GetFolder($folder.Url + $spFolderPath)
            }

            #Check to see if subfolder already exists
            #and create it if not
            $testFolder = $currentFolder.SubFolders[$_.Name]
            if ($testFolder -eq $null) {
                write-host "`nAdding folder" $_.Name "to" $docLibrary.Title "in" $web.Title "..." -foregroundcolor Green
                $newFolder = $currentFolder.SubFolders.Add($_.Name)
            }
            else
            {
                write-host "`nFolder" $_.Name "already exists in" $docLibrary.Title "and shall not be created" -foregroundcolor Red
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        #Generate file path for upload into SharePoint
        if ($FlattenStructure) {
            $spFilePath = ("/" + $_.Name)
        }
        else
        {
            $spFilePath = ($_.FullName.Replace($LocalPath,"")).Replace("\","/")
        }

        $spFullPath = $folder.Url + $spFilePath

        #Check if the file exists and the overwrite option is selected before adding the file
        if ((!$web.GetFile($spFullPath).Exists) -or ($Overwrite)) {
            #Add file
            write-host "`nCopying" $_.Name "to" $spFullPath.Replace("/" + $_.Name,"") "in" $web.Title "..." -foregroundcolor Green
            $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($spFullPath, $_.OpenRead(), $true)
            $spItem = $spFile.Item

            #Walk through manifest XML file and configure column values on the file
            $metadataManifest.Columns.Column | ForEach-Object {

                #Single value text columns
                try
                {
                    if (($_.Type -eq "Text") -or
                        ($_.Type -eq "Choice") -or
                        ($_.Type -eq "Boolean") -or
                        ($_.Type -eq "Number") -or
                        ($_.Type -eq "Currency")) {
                        $columnName = $_.Name
                        write-host "Setting value on column"$columnName "..." -foregroundcolor Blue
                        $_.Values.Value | ForEach-Object {
                            $spItem[$columnName] = $_
                            write-host "Value set to"$_
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {}

                #Multiple line text column
                try
                {
                    if ($_.Type -eq "Note") {
                        $columnName = $_.Name
                        write-host "Setting value on column"$columnName "..." -foregroundcolor Blue
                        [string]$multiLineValue = $null
                        $_.Values.Value | ForEach-Object {
                            $multiLineValue = $multiLineValue + $_ + "`n"
                        }
                        $spItem[$columnName] = $multiLineValue
                        write-host "Value on multiiple line text column set"
                    }
                }
                catch {}

                #Multiple choice columns
                try
                {
                    if ($_.Type -eq "MultiChoice") {
                        $columnName = $_.Name
                        write-host "Setting value on column"$columnName "..." -foregroundcolor Blue
                        [string]$multiChoiceValue = ";#"
                        $_.Values.Value | ForEach-Object {
                            $multiChoiceValue = $multiChoiceValue + $_ + ";#"
                            write-host "Value"$_ "added to column"
                        }
                        $spItem[$columnName] = $multiChoiceValue
                    }
                }
                catch {}

                #Hyperlink columns
                try
                {
                    if ($_.Type -eq "URL") {
                        $columnName = $_.Name
                        write-host "Setting value on column"$columnName "..." -foregroundcolor Blue
                        $urlFieldValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue
                        $_.Values.Description | ForEach-Object {
                            $urlFieldValue.Description = $_
                        }
                        $_.Values.Value | ForEach-Object {
                            $urlFieldValue.Url = $_
                        }
                        $spItem[$columnName] = $urlFieldValue
                        write-host "Value set to"$urlFieldValue.Url
                    }
                }
                catch {}

                #Single User column
                try
                {
                    if ($_.Type -eq "User") {
                        $columnName = $_.Name
                        $user = $null
                        write-host "Setting value on column"$columnName "..." -foregroundcolor Blue
                        $_.Values.Value | ForEach-Object {
                            #Check to see if SharePoint group exists in the site collection
                            if ($web.SiteGroups[$_])
                            {
                                #Set account variable to SPGroup
                                $account = $web.SiteGroups[$_]
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                #Set account variable to SPUser
                                $account = $web.EnsureUser($_)
                            }
                            $spItem[$columnName] = $account
                            write-host "Value set to"$_
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {}

                #Multiple User column
                try
                {
                    if ($_.Type -eq "UserMulti") {
                        $columnName = $_.Name
                        $user = $null
                        $userField = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection
                        write-host "Setting value on column"$columnName "..." -foregroundcolor Blue
                        $_.Values.Value | ForEach-Object {
                            #Check to see if SharePoint group exists in the site collection
                            if ($web.SiteGroups[$_])
                            {
                                #Set account variable to SPGroup
                                $account = $web.SiteGroups[$_]
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                #Set account variable to SPUser
                                $account = $web.EnsureUser($_)
                            }
                            $userValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web, $account.ID, $account.Name)
                            $userField.Add($userValue)
                            write-host "Value"$_ "added to column"
                        }
                        $spItem[$columnName] = $userField
                    }
                }
                catch {}

                #Single value Managed Metadata column
                try
                {
                    if ($_.Type -eq "TaxonomyFieldType") {
                        $columnName = $_.Name
                        $taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $web.Site
                        $termStore = $taxonomySession.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore

                        $taxonomyField = $docLibrary.Fields[$columnName]

                        $termSet = $termStore.GetTermSet($taxonomyField.TermSetId)
                        write-host "Setting value on column"$columnName "..." -foregroundcolor Blue
                        $_.Values.Value | ForEach-Object {
                            $termCollection = $termSet.GetTerms($_, $true)
                            if ($termCollection.Count -eq 0)
                            { 
                                $term = $termSet.CreateTerm($_, 1033)
                                $termStore.CommitAll()
                            }
                            else
                        {
                                $term = $termCollection[0]
                            }
                            $taxonomyField.SetFieldValue($spItem, $term)
                            write-host "Value set to"$_
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {}

                #Multi value Managed Metadata column
                try
                {
                    if ($_.Type -eq "TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti") {
                        $columnName = $_.Name
                        $taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $web.Site
                        $termStore = $taxonomySession.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore

                        $taxonomyField = $docLibrary.Fields[$columnName]
                        $tfvc = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection($taxonomyField)

                        $termSet = $termStore.GetTermSet($taxonomyField.TermSetId)
                        write-host "Setting value on column"$columnName "..." -foregroundcolor Blue
                        $_.Values.Value | ForEach-Object {
                            $termCollection = $termSet.GetTerms($_, $true)
                            if ($termCollection.Count -eq 0)
                            { 
                                $term = $termSet.CreateTerm($_, 1033)
                                $termStore.CommitAll()
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $term = $termCollection[0]
                            }
                            $valueString = "-1;#" + $term.Name + "|" + $term.Id.ToString()
                            $taxonomyValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue($valueString)
                            $tfvc.Add($taxonomyValue)
                            write-host "Value"$_ "added to column"
                        }
                        $taxonomyField.SetFieldValue($spItem, $tfvc)
                    }
                }
                catch {}

                #Update document with new column values
                $spItem.SystemUpdate($false)
            }

            #Check in file to document library (if required)
            #MinorCheckIn=0, MajorCheckIn=1, OverwriteCheckIn=2
            if ($CheckIn) {
                if ($spFile.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") {
                    $spFile.CheckIn("File copied from " + $filePath, 1)
                    write-host $spfile.Name"checked in"
                }
            }

            #Approve file (if required)
            if ($Approve) {
                if ($spItem.ListItems.List.EnableModeration -eq $true) {
                    $spFile.Approve("File automatically approved after copying from " + $filePath)
                    if ($spItem["Approval Status"] -eq 0) { write-host $spfile.Name"approved" }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "`nFile"$_.Name "already exists in" $spFullPath.Replace("/" + $_.Name,"") "and shall not be uploaded" -foregroundcolor Red
        }
    }
}
}
catch [System.SystemException]
{ 
    write-host "The script has stopped because there has been an error.  "$_.Message
}
finally
{
    $web.Dispose()
}
}
write-host "SharePoint 2010 Multiple File Upload Script - Get-SPScripts.com"
```

More information is available in CodePlex; http://spfileupload.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Get-SPScripts.Copy-FilesToSP.ps1

Comment: He didn't ask for a Powershell solution. If we could use any language for this, I'd be recommending a VBA solution.